Правильно ли здесь написано: получилось или получился?
Текст:
Как у него это получилось?

или
Как у него это получился?

Какой из них правильный, и почему?


Согласование слов в русском языке включает в себя приведение грамматических категорий слов в предложение в соответствие друг с другом, чтобы обеспечить правильность и смысловую связь. В русском языке важными категориями, которые необходимо согласовывать, являются род, число и лицо.

Разберем это на примере предложения "как это получился"
Это — существительное среднего рода, единственного числа; лица у него нет (оно только у личных местоимений), соответственно слово "получился" должно быть согласовано в роде и числе со словом "это".
Для правильного согласования в роде нужно задать вопросы "Что оно делало?" или "Что оно сделало?", если слово среднего рода. В нашем случае не подходит ни один из них, соответственно слова не согласованы в роде.
Для правильного согласования в числе нужно определить, в какой форме слово (в русском языке у слов есть формы множественного и единственного чисел). В нашем случае у обоих слов форма единственного числа, соответственно слова согласованы в числе.
Правильно ли здесь написано: получилось или получился?
Правильный вариант:
Как у него это получилось?

В данном случае слова согласованы и в числе, и в роде.
